# Leaflet maps crashes the App( via PhoneGap/Android) on Zoom

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webkit, leaflet

So I'm using Leaflet.js mapping library(with OpenStreetMaps, for now) in this html5 App (a very simple example, so I doubt posting code is needed.), and using PhoneGap( v4.2.0...I think). I'm deploying/testing for Android. It works well enough, until you zoom/pinch-zoom, in which case the App crashes(not always and on different zoom-levels).

I've tried finding out what exactly happens(using abd), but to no avail, after a wild-goose chase my results are inconclusive:

```
F/libc    ( 1902): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 1915 (WebViewCoreThre)
I/DEBUG   (  787): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  787): Build fingerprint: 'unknown'
I/DEBUG   (  787): pid: 1902, tid: 1915, name: UNKNOWN  >>> package.mypackage <<<
I/DEBUG   (  787): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
```

Not very helpful. Gonna try using the latest version of Phonegap next...little hope. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this issue: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/909

It appears to be an issue with the Android 4.1 browser, and can be worked around by setting:

`window.L_DISABLE_3D = true;`

before you include leaflet.js so that hardware acceleration isn't used. It fixed the problem for me in my current Sencha 2.1.1 + PhoneGap Build app. The zooming looks a bit worse but I haven't been able to make it crash so far.

Comment: I have tried this previously, but it didn't work...I can't remember if I ran it before the include. I'll try again with the latest version of phonegap and make sure my order is correct. Will get back to you, cheers!

Comment: Yeah, so that fixed it, I just wasn't setting it BEFORE including leaflet! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The latest phonegap version is 2.5.0 (see https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/tags).

You can try next code to handle any errors in your application with uncompressed scripts:

```
window.onerror = function (message, url, line) {
    alert(message + '\n' + url + ': ' + line + '\n' + navigator.userAgent);
    // console.log(message, url, line, navigator.userAgent);
}
```

When you will know error and place where it raised, you can try debug your code with remote console: http://jsconsole.com/ to get your `console.log` messages (add timestamp to see real sequence).